# Error 404 not found while using command sudo apt-get update - PPA shimmerproject has no release file

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

I am getting an error while using the command :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The error:

[image: this shows the error i am getting]

How can I solve it?
since i am new to ubuntu i really dont know much so please help me

Comment: Just remove that "shimmerproject" PPA you added because it's not for your release or any other still supported.

Comment: You added a repository which is probably not maintained anymore, you should find and delete the file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message indicates that you have added a PPA that doesn't contain a proper file for your Ubuntu version. You can fix this problem by simply remove the PPA that cause the problem (note that no new software will be added), then find the proper PPA location and add it.

To remove a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
```

in your case try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:shimmerproject/ppa
```

and then

```
sudo apt update
```